# Invalid syntax when using apply with conditional lambda with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a `cost` column to the `w1_weekdays`. I want to multiply 'kwh_usage' by `onP_price` when the `end_time_hour` is equal to `0, 1, 2`. For all other hours, I want to multiply by `offP_price`.

[image]

I used apply and lambda to do this.

```
w1_weekdays['cost'] = w1_weekdays['end_time_hour'].apply(lambda (onP_price, offP_price):\
                                                     (onP_price * w1_weekdays['kwh_usage'])\
                                                     if w1_weekdays['end_time_hour'] in (0,1,2)\
                                                     else (offP_price * w1_weekdays['kwh_usage']))
```

However, I get this error

[image]

Is the code even correct? And why the invalid syntax error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think better here is use vectorized solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) by boolean mask created by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and last multiple column `kwh_usage`:

```
mask = w1_weekdays['end_time_hour'].isin([0,1,2])

w1_weekdays['cost'] = np.where(mask, onP_price , offP_price) *  w1_weekdays['kwh_usage']
```